# Form didnt send any value

Tags: php, html, forms

Soo, i have a form that i use to send data to mysql but when i click submit the form didnt send anything to mysql but there is no error shown either. I also try `var_dump($_POST)` and it show no data. How'd i fix it? thanks.

The code:

```
  <?php
  include '../koneksi.php';
  $awal_sewa = $_POST['awal_sewa'];
  $akhir_sewa = $_POST['akhir_sewa'];

  $number_days = ((strtotime($akhir_sewa) - strtotime($awal_sewa)) / (60 * 60 * 24));
  $total_price = 0;

  $harga = mysqli_query($koneksi, "select harga from kamar");

  $id = $_GET['id'];
  $data = mysqli_query($koneksi,"select * from kamar where id='$id'");
  while($d = mysqli_fetch_array($data)){

    $total_price = $number_days * $d['harga'];
    ?>

        <form role="form" action="store.php">


                  <input type="hidden" name="id_kamar" class="inside" value="<?php echo $d['id']; ?>">

                  <input type="date" class="form-control" name="konfirmasi_awal_sewa" placeholder="Enter Number" value="<?php echo $awal_sewa; ?>" readonly>

                  <input type="date" class="form-control" name="konfirmasi_akhir_sewa" placeholder="" value="<?php echo $akhir_sewa; ?>" readonly>

                  <input type="text" class="form-control col-sm" name="total_hari" value="<?php echo (int)$number_days;?> hari" readonly>

                  <input type="text" class="form-control col-sm" name="total_harga" value="Rp<?php echo (int)$total_price;?>,-" readonly>
                <?php
              }
              ?>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sewa</button>
        </form>
```

Store.php:

```
<?php var_dump($_POST); ?>
```

Comment: Add method="POST" in your <form> tag.

Comment: Also you are using both $_POST and $_GET, you can't use both for same form. You should use $_POST if form method is post.

Comment: You're also wide open to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work). You should use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead.

Comment: @UmairMalik He can use both through **AJAX** but not through `form`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to specify `method` property for the form. The default `method` is **GET**

You need to change the form in the while loop to be

```
<form method="POST" role="form" action="store.php">
```